Why does PageSpeed Insights report a large "Other" in Minimize main-thread work?
Running a report on https://www.digitalocean.com via https://pagespeed.web.dev, I get back a result for desktop with a multiple-second-long Total Blocking Time and a recommendation to Minimize main-thread work, attributed to around 30s of time taken with the majority of that being classified as "Other".


Compared with running Lighthouse myself against the site though, I get back a 0ms Total Blocking Time and while the Minimize main-thread work recommendation is listed (in grey, not even a warning), it is attributed to only a couple of seconds of time taken.


Why are the Total Blocking Time, and the Minimize main-thread work time, so drastically different between PageSpeed Insights and local Lighthouse? This doesn't feel explainable purely by device throttling?

PSI uses a specific device profile for its lab tests; local lighthouse reports use the specs of your local machine, so if you have a higher performing machine vs the test machine your lighthouse scores will bias towards indicating higher performance
Also keep in mind these reports are all lab data and don't reflect the real experience of users; consider it a rough guide to guide performance improvement projects.
